# Excel macro loop thru column to assign cell name box

Tags: excel, loops, vba

I want to populate the name box for a cell with the value from an adjacent cell.  This macro works.

```
Sub NameBox()
   ' populates name box w/ value from adjacent cell
   ActiveCell.Name = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Value
   ' steps down to next cell
   ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
End Sub
```

I assign a key stroke and iterate through each cell in the column which is pretty easy but I think it can be improved with a loop.

I tried this.

```
Sub NameBoxLoop()
   Dim cel As Range
   For Each cel In Range("C:C").Cells
      If cel.Value <> "" Then
         cel.Name = cel.Offset(0, -1).Value
      End If
   Next cel
End Sub
```

But I get the following debug error

> cel.Name = Application-defined or object-defined error

The loop logic looks right, if I replace the variable cel.Name with cel.Value the loop will complete.

Searches haven't provided an answer to the cel.Name error.  Any help in resolving this error is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your formula works. But maybe your environment is not optimal, because you have no error-correction there - and names have limitations.

So I am guessing eigther you don't have values in column B or column B has values which are already used as names for other cells.

In both cases your loop would break.

Try this to loop anyways, but consider error-proving your code:

```
Sub NameBoxLoop()
   On Error Resume Next
   Dim cel As Range
   For Each cel In Range("C:C").Cells
      If cel.Value <> "" Then
         cel.Name = cel.Offset(0, -1).Value
      End If
   Next cel
end sub
```

*Edit:*

as a suggestion, you might want to consider using the `Names` listing.

Here is an example from excel-help:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="test", RefersTo:="=sheet1!$a$1:$c$20"
```

And here some of the objectmembers:

- Add
- Item
- Count

Comment: You beat me to my answer - I BET the challenge is that your loop is trying to assign same / blank names to cells

Comment: That did it.  Thanks for the help.  I'm still a hack at this stuff, looks like I need to get a better handle on error correct best practices.  I'll also spend some time trying to figure out what the exact error is.  Although it could simply be as the 2nd reply suggests, assigning blank names to cells.

Comment: @PeterPerreault use the Debugger, BreakPoints and `Debug.Print` or Variable-Viewer to get a good picture of what is happening ;)